# vs 2017: unable to find add new class library project option

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have created new MVC solution in VS 2017:
[image]

When I right click on on this solution and add new item, i get this:
[image]

But I am not able to see any option to add new class library project. I want to add BL/DAL to my solution. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to right click on the solution.

[image]

### Alternative Approach

Create a blank solution first, and then add projects.

[image]

Comment: Looks like I'm doing something wrong. Check your solution icon and compare it with mine, plus i see output type of my solution as class library. Check what I see when i right click on solution and hover on add: https://ibb.co/dbVuLT

Comment: I am using vs2017 15.7.4

Comment: I'm not sure how you create the solution. Alternative approach is to start with blank solution, and add projects. I updated my answer.